# The "LOGIC" in Quizes PHP+MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, logic

I have a Database (MySQL) where is a table called: "dbtest" has the following fields,

```
id + v + o1 + o2 + o3 + o4 + g
to clarify that:
v: are the questions field
o1: the first answer
o2: the second
o3: third
o4: forth
g: is the right answer, where I put the number of the right answer for example, if I had a question with a correct answer "o3" the value of "g" should be "3"
```

(I did that myself thinking would be easier hopefully)

We yet did not reach the point I know, the thing is that I'm building a quiz program standing on the previous scheme, I made a page that calls the questions from the database and post them one below the other, the code was as the following:

```
    <?php
include "config.inc";

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM test";
$query = mysql_query($SQL) or die();

echo "<form action=grade.php method=POST>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

echo "<p>$row[id]. ";
echo "$row[v]<br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=answer[$row[id]] value=$row[o1]>$row[o1]</input><br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=answer[$row[id]] value=$row[o2]>$row[o2]</input><br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=answer[$row[id]] value=$row[o3]>$row[o3]</input><br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=answer[$row[id]] value=$row[o4]>$row[o4]</input><br>";

}

echo "<input type=submit name=submit value=Check>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

The problem is when I wanted to write the "grade.php" page I fell off an edge, I absolutely lost, I could do it if there was just one question in the database, so no need to enter a loop, but since the database is expected to receive tons of question I lost control.

I was trying something like,

```
<?php
include "config.inc";
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM test";
    $query = mysql_query($SQL) or die();

    $n = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $n++;
    $ques[$n] = $_POST['answer'];
    if ($ques[$n] == $row[g]) {
    echo "<font color=green>Correct</font>"; }

    else {
    echo "<font color=red>Incorrect<br></font>"; }
}
    ?>
```

But did not make it, all what I need is to process the questions and give right/wrong answers, for every right answer (+1) for every wrong one (-1) then I will post the sum mathematically.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would just like to inform/remind you that we are not a forum; please refrain from posting questions of this style (with informalities) next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML your have to change radio button :

1. No need to add `</input>`,
2. For value you set answer number,
3. Add quotes for attributes

---

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$answer[$row['id']].'" value="1" />'.$row['o1'].'<br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$answer[$row['id']].'" value="2" />'.$row['o2'].'<br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$answer[$row['id']].'" value="3" />'.$row['o3'].'<br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$answer[$row['id']].'" value="4" />'.$row['o4'].'<br>';
```

In PHP :

1. You create some variables to store good and bad answers,
2. You check if value of `$row['g']` is equal to answer number

---

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test") or die();

$good = 0; // Number of good answers.
$bad = 0; // Number of bad answers.

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    if ( $_POST['answer'][$row['id']] == $row['g'] )
    {
        echo '<span style="color: green;">Correct</span>';
        $good++;
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<span style="color: red;">Incorrect</span>';
        $bad++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!! )) I've modified the code, and it is now working exactly the way I want :)